# Cypress fails with tsconfig.json node_modules/* path

Tags: typescript, webpack, cypress

So I've ran into an issue, similar to the one here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/16188

With Cypress and a `tsconfig.json` having path/baseURL set up like so:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "app/packs/*"
  ]
```

Will cause an error:

```
TypeError: validateOptions is not a function
    at new SourceMapDevToolPlugin
```

Removing either the `baseURL` portion OR the `node_modules/*` portion fixes the issue. However, I am not exactly sure why. I am not exactly super in tune with TypeScript or webpack but removing the `node_modules/*` portion doesn't seem to affect the web application (I imagine removing the `baseURL` would cause some issues). But I am not sure if there is a side effect I am not aware of?

My guess is that Cypress is using the `tsconfig.json` to look for packages and is looking at the wrong `node_modules` path....but is it safe to just remove the `node_modules/*` from the paths or am I missing something major?

Comment: Thanks for the fix of removing node_modules from paths in tsconfig.json. That seems to work in my Rails 6 project! I never would have even thought to look there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be resolved by removing the `baseURL` portion or removing the `node_modules/*`

This seems to be cypress "official" solution after posting a github issue. FWIW I did not see any issues in removing the `node_modules/*` path.